# CodeIgniter Framework / Multiple MySQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Part 1 (the MySQL part)**

I'm using CI and MySQL (same server). I've never worked with multiple tables working together, I'm not sure if I need to setup relations or if PHP will do the talking for me.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Table: Items (this table is where each item is stored)

Table: Users (User ID, password, account information, etc)

Table: Collection (This table will say that user x has # amount of item x)

I already have the Items and Users tables setup, but I'm stumped on what to do with the collection one.

**Part 2 (the CI/PHP part)**

Once I have the SQL setup, what is the best way to have PHP add/remove/update listings in Collection and display related information based off of what is in someones collection

Ex

Items Fields (id, Name, Value)

Users Fields (id, Name, Password MD5, Last Login, etc)

Collection Fields (id, itemid, userid, amount)

I'd like to be able to display all items for the currently logged in user, logged in user variable is coming from here

```
function account_info($username)
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');

        $result = $query->row();

        return array(
            'id' => $result->id,
            'firstname' => $result->firstname,
            'lastname' => $result->lastname,
            'email' => $result->email,
            'joindate' => $result->joindate
            );

    }
```

Say my unique userid is 1 and the following lines are in the Collection table:

id | userid | itemid | amount

1  | 1      | 23     | 1

2  | 1      | 25     | 3

3  | 2      | 20     | 5

4  | 1      | 24     | 1

I'd like it to return only lines 1,2,4 with the information of what itemid 23,25 and 24 are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query='SELECT * 
FROM Collections 
INNER JOIN Items ON Collections.itemid=Items.id 
WHERE userid=?';
$params=array();
$params[]=$user_id;

$result=$this->db->query($query,$params);
$result=$result->result_array();
//$result=$result->row_array(); // for single row

print_r($result); //for your debugging
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is using a join statement in your SQL query.  We could write out a SQL query, but CodeIgniter's active record class will help us to simplify this (see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).  In your model, you could write your query similar to:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Collections');
$this->db->join('Items', 'Collections.itemid = Company.id', 'inner');
```

You can also tweak this to select the exact data that you want like you would any SQL query:

```
$this->db->select('Collections.userid, Collections.amount, Items.name, Items.value');
```

To select data of a specific individual (for example: the user with '1' as an id number), you could use:

```
$this->db->where('Collections.userid', '1');
```

As a final result, your complete query could look similar to:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Collections');
$this->db->join('Items', 'Collections.itemid = Company.id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('Collections.userid', '1');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

You can also add left, right, outer, inner, left outer, or right outer as a third parameter to the `$this->db->join()` function to allow for left joins, right joins, etc.

I would recommend using the Active Record class when possible in your CodeIgniter applications. It will help keep your queries clean, organized, and readable. Definitely have a look at it: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Would look simpler if you'd chain the queries to make it readable